# How do I crop faces based on bounding boxes in Tensorflow.js?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow.js

I need to crop faces which are detected in BlazeFace Model then send the image over to a custom model I made. I have already implemented the face detection with the bounding boxes but am stuck at cropping the face out.

I have the coordinates of the landmarks and the bottomRight and topLeft but I do not know how to do so. In python with tensorflow their exist functions to do so but with tensorflow.js I can't find anything for this.

**Rendering Bounding Boxes on Face**

```
    const faces = await bfModel
      .estimateFaces(tensor, returnTensors)
      .catch(e => console.log(e));
    console.log(faces);

    // Faces is an array of objects
    if (!isEmpty(faces)) {
      setModelFaces({ faces });
    }

  const renderBoundingBoxes = () => {
    const { faces } = modelFaces;
    const scale = {
      height: styles.camera.height / tensorDims.height,
      width: styles.camera.width / tensorDims.width
    };
    const flipHorizontal = Platform.OS === "ios" ? false : true;
    if (!isEmpty(faces)) {
      return faces.map((face, i) => {
        const { topLeft, bottomRight } = face;
        const bbLeft = topLeft.dataSync()[0] * scale.width;
        const boxStyle = Object.assign({}, styles.bbox, {
          left: flipHorizontal
            ? previewWidth - bbLeft - previewLeft
            : bbLeft + previewLeft,
          top: topLeft.dataSync()[1] * scale.height + 20,
          width:
            (bottomRight.dataSync()[0] - topLeft.dataSync()[0]) * scale.width,
          height:
            (bottomRight.dataSync()[1] - topLeft.dataSync()[1]) * scale.height
        });

        return <View style={boxStyle}></View>;
        1;
      });
    }
  };
```

**Output from console.log(faces):**

```
Array [
  Object {
    "bottomRight": Tensor {
      "dataId": Object {},
      "dtype": "float32",
      "id": 220600,
      "isDisposedInternal": false,
      "kept": false,
      "rankType": "1",
      "scopeId": 426282,
      "shape": Array [
        2,
      ],
      "size": 2,
      "strides": Array [],
    },
    "landmarks": Tensor {
      "dataId": Object {},
      "dtype": "float32",
      "id": 220602,
      "isDisposedInternal": false,
      "kept": false,
      "rankType": "2",
      "scopeId": 426286,
      "shape": Array [
        6,
        2,
      ],
      "size": 12,
      "strides": Array [
        2,
      ],
    },
    "probability": Tensor {
      "dataId": Object {},
      "dtype": "float32",
      "id": 220592,
      "isDisposedInternal": false,
      "kept": false,
      "rankType": "1",
      "scopeId": 426249,
      "shape": Array [
        1,
      ],
      "size": 1,
      "strides": Array [],
    },
    "topLeft": Tensor {
      "dataId": Object {},
      "dtype": "float32",
      "id": 220599,
      "isDisposedInternal": false,
      "kept": false,
      "rankType": "1",
      "scopeId": 426280,
      "shape": Array [
        2,
      ],
      "size": 2,
      "strides": Array [],
    },
  },
]
```

Comment: Which line is cropping the faces ? I guess `tensor` contains the image, right ?

Comment: I have not done the cropping cause I do not know how to crop it. But faces contains the array of objects like the landmarks, probability, topLeft and bottomRight. I used them to draw the bounding boxes.

Comment: Yes tensor has the full image that is passed to the model.

Comment: I have added the output from console.log(faces)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

image can be cropped using `tf.image.cropAndResize`. The tensor should be a 4d tensor. If the image is a 3d tensor, it first needs to be expanded. The crop expected height and width should be passed as argument to `copAndResize`

```
boxes = tf.concat([topLeftTensor, bottomRightTensor]).reshape([-1, 4])
crop = tf.image.cropAndResize(images, boxes, [0], [height, width])
```

Comment: topLeft and bottomRight are both 1D Tensors so the code here combines them into a 2D Tensor right?
Yes the image is a 3D tensor so I would expandDims and expand it on the 1st Dimension?
Why is the box indices set to [0]?

Comment: boxes should be a 2d tensor. I updated the code. Expandims or reshape can be used to expand your image if it is a 3d tensor. The box indices is set to [0] to represent the first batch. Obviously if you have multiple batches, you need to update the indices accordingly

Comment: Alright I will try it. So far my model I will be sending a single batch at a time for now and see how it performs.

Answer (score 0):

I dont sure but it can work:

```
let img_4d = tf.expandDims(inputTF3D, axis=0)
const start = predictions[id].topLeft;
const end = predictions[id].bottomRight;
let boxes = tf.concat([start, end]);
boxes = tf.reshape(boxes,[-1, 4])
let crop = tf.image.cropAndResize(img_4d, boxes, [0], [IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH])
```

https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/3914